# Google feed verse Google Crawling

Tags: google-api, robots.txt

We have our simple products listed at catalog in order to have them available in our Google shopping feed. Is there a way to remove these products from being crawled by google bot so they don't show up in our crawl errors in webmaster tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent products from being crawled by Google you can set the meta robots to NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW.

If you want to do this for **all** Simple products in your catalog you can add this to your local.xml file:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
    <reference name="head">
       <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
```

Note: if you do not have a local.xml file you can create it in app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/ and Magento will include it automatically.

This will result in your simple product pages robots meta tag to update to:

```
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW" />
```

If you do not want it to be applied to all Simple products and instead want to hand select the products to apply this to you can 
-log into the Magento admin 
-go to Catalog->Manage Products 
-open the product you want to edit
-click on the Design tab on the left
-paste the following code into 'Custom Layout Update'

```
    <reference name="head">
       <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
    </reference>
```

This will let search engines know not to crawl this individual item.

Comment: So we could create an attribute for no-follow products and set only those.

Comment: I hadn't thought of using a custom attribute but yes you could do that.  You would need to create the product attribute and make sure that the attribute is part of the attribute set for the products you want to effect (or you could add it the new attribute to all attribute sets).  Then you would need to edit your head.phtml file to call the attribute in. Here is a similar item where the person was calling a custom tag you could instead call your custom variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461061/echo-a-product-attribute-in-magento-head-phtml

Comment: Lots of modules do this already for you: Inchoo_ProductMetaRobots https://github.com/Marko-M/Inchoo_ProductMetaRobots/ & Yoast_MetaRobots https://github.com/ho-nl/Yoast_MetaRobots to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have an SEO extension installed you can change the products to NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW. Otherwise you can ban them with robots.txt:

```
Disallow: /your/product/url/here.html
```

Even better: leave the pages live and 301 redirect them to a new version or a more applicable version of the product. Perhaps even a search query that will display relevant results of similar products.

Answer (score 0):

Um that is a tricky problem with the usual answers already posted here is my tupence with my SEO experience.

Robots Meta tag - if this is set to no you're telling Google you don't want it be ranked or as it's put in the meat tag itself put in google's "index". If Googlebot visits this page its' already crawled it hence if the page goes and Googlebot comes back you'll always get a 404 error, the previous contribution of "To prevent products.." doesn't work because Google need to index the page first to see the robots meta tag in the first place so it "has" to spider the page to see the message. So doing this is pointless if you want to actually stop the 404 errors this however will stop pages getting ranked and solve duplicate content issues.

Robot.txt file - this is a better option however if you do say a site search "site:mysite.com" get to the last results and click the unfiltered message and get to the last results again you'll see, depending on your site, various pages with a message basically saying that the site has blocked the page in it's robots.txt file.  That's all well and great but Googlebot has to index the pages for the message to be shown in the first place and if the page goes... yes you've guessed it 404 page error... this should slow down crawling rates and will stop pages being ranked - this goes to show it doesn't do what it should do - stop search engines indexing pages altogether.

My experience of SEO is Google assumes why would you want to put public content and not want it indexed. I'm not that familiar with feeds since Google shut down that form of marketing in SEO and made it paid but there must be a better solution to your product feed.  You need to solve that problem not the indexing one - in my mind you'll never fix it.

The best option in my mind is if you can do this put your catalogue feeds in specific folders - for example date them by month and when they're no longer needed instead of 301 put a 410 redirect on the entire folder and that will solve you - that won't work if you can't order them and you need to reuse some - the real solution is to change how you are displaying the feed. Not sure why you'd want to actually do that - some kind of automated system I'd presume!